# Identifying instances based on unique attributes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm working on a project and it would make it easier for me to code if we can identify class attributes based on their unique instances.
example

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, unique_id):
        self.unique_id = unique_id
```

and later

```
class1 = MyClass(1)
class2 = MyClass(2)
```

Is it possible to do get the object class1 as an output if

```
output = instance whose unique_id == 1
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to find that instance among other instances?

Comment: Could you just take the `id` of the object itself using the [`id` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)?

Comment: Still not clear. Where and how are those instances preserved? are they in a container? please add more information about the problem because this seems like it can be solved with a simple `if` condition.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh i got the id from the object using id(object) but how to get the object from the id

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a dict of instances:

```
class MyClass:
    _instances = {}

    def __init__(self, unique_id):
        self.unique_id = unique_id
        self._instances[unique_id] = self

    @classmethod
    def instance_by_id(cls, id):
        return cls._instances[id]


a = MyClass(1)
b = MyClass(2)


c = MyClass.instance_by_id(1)

print(c)
print(a)
#<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fa9dd0bfbe0> 
#<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fa9dd0bfbe0>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option A :**

If you are planing on adding the id's in a consecutive way you could enter them all into a list :

```
class_list = []
class_list.append(MyClass(1))
class_list.append(MyClass(2))
```

And then get them using

```
class_list[index]
```

**Option B :**

If you arent going to them consecutively you could do the following

```
class_dict = {}
class_dict{"some_id"} = MyClass("some_id")
class_dict{"some_id2"} = MyClass("some_id2")
```

and then access as following :

```
class_dict["some_id"]
```

**Option C - Prefered:**

Personally I would recommend the following :

```
class MyClass:
    static_dict = {}
    def __init__(self, unique_id):
        self.unique_id = unique_id
        MyClass.static_dict[unique_id] = self

    def get_class_by_id(unique_id):
        return static_dict[unique_id]
```

and then you could access as following:

```
MyClass.get_class_by_id("some_id")
```